# How to retrieve a user-defined type from a for loop?

Tags: reference, rust, borrow-checker

I defined an `Attribute` type and I have a `Vec<Attribute>` that I am looping over to retrieve the "best" one. This was similar to my first attempt:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Attribute;

impl Attribute {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self
    }
}

fn example(attrs: Vec<Attribute>, root: &mut Attribute) {
    let mut best_attr = &Attribute::new();
    for a in attrs.iter() {
        if is_best(a) {
            best_attr = a;
        }
    }
    *root = *best_attr;
}

// simplified for example
fn is_best(_: &Attribute) -> bool {
    true
}
```

I had the following compile error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
  --> src/lib.rs:17:13
   |
17 |     *root = *best_attr;
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content
```

After some searching for a solution, I resolved the error by doing the following:

1. Adding a `#[derive(Clone)]` attribute to my `Attribute` struct
2. Replacing the final statement with `*root = best_attr.clone();`

I don't fully understand why this works, and I feel like this is a rough solution to the problem I was having. How does this resolve the error, and is this the correct way to solve this problem?

Comment: Not a Rust expert, but IIRC it's because `root` has different scope than `best_attr`, and `best_attr`'s memory could be reclaimed by the time `root` would have a chance to reference it. So it's not allowed. `clone()` provides a scope-compatible copy, so it's allowed.

Comment: Short answer: it boils down to Rust’s ownership model. Only one thing can own a piece of data at a time.

Comment: Note that creating a default attribute first is wasteful, instead you could probably set `best_attr` to `None`, and then have `best_attr = Some(a)` in your loop. Of course, it would require having some pattern matching at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are experiencing the basis of the Rust memory model:

- every object can (and must!) be owned by only exactly one other object
- most types are *never* implicitly copied and *always* moved (there are some exceptions: types that implement [`Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html))

Take this code for example:

```
let x = String::new();
let y = x;
println!("{}", x);
```

it generates the error:

```
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `x`
 --> src/main.rs:4:20
  |
3 |     let y = x;
  |             - value moved here
4 |     println!("{}", x);
  |                    ^ value borrowed here after move
  |
  = note: move occurs because `x` has type `std::string::String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

`x`, of type `String`, is not implicitly copyable, and thus has been *moved* into `y`. `x` cannot be used any longer.

In your code, when you write `*root = *best_attr`, you are first dereferencing the reference `best_attr`, then assigning the dereferenced value to `*root`. Your `Attribute` type is not `Copy`, thus this assignment should be a *move*.

Then, the compiler complains:

```
cannot move out of borrowed content
```

Indeed, `best_attr` is an immutable reference, which does *not* allow you to take ownership of the value behind it (it doesn't even allow modifying it). Allowing such a move would put the object owning the value behind the reference in an undefined state, which is exactly what Rust aims to prevent.

---

In this case, your best option is indeed to create a new object with the same value as the first one, which is exactly what the trait [`Clone`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html) is made for.

`#[derive(Clone)]` allows you to mark your structs as `Clone`-able, as long as all of their fields are `Clone`. In more complex cases, you'll have to implement the trait by hand.